# Why wp_die() doesn't work with wp_redirect but exit() works

Tags: plugin-development, functions

I have a question related to the behaviour of WordPress.
I coded a function which on-call redirects the user to a page inside WordPress. I used it with `add_query_arg()`.
Here is the function I created.

```
function wg_uep_license_fail_redirect( $message ) {
        update_option( 'wg_uep_license_status', 'invalid' );

        if ( ! empty( $message ) ) {
            $redirectUrl = admin_url( 'admin.php?page=wp_uep');
            $finalizedUrl = add_query_arg( array(
                'license_activation'    => 'false',
                'message'               => urlencode( $message ),
            ), $redirectUrl );
            wp_redirect( $finalizedUrl );
            // wp_die();
            exit;
        }
    }
```

As you can see the function has a message parameter. Now if I call the function like this.

```
$message = 'hello dead';
wg_uep_license_fail_redirect( $message );
```

Everything works fine if I use `exit` but if I uncomment `wp_die()` and remove the `exit`. Nothing seems to work.

Now my question is simple what is the difference. How WordPress handles the `wp_die` or `exit`?

**NOTE: `die()` also works but not `wp_die()`.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your context, `wp_die()` will behave differently. This means if you're inside an AJAX request it will do something else than say a standard http request.

So depending on from where you're actually calling it, this can make a difference. Say you're in a normal http request, then it will call [`_default_wp_die_handler()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.5.1/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L3387) which besides adding headers also outputs HTML - which is not what you want.

Just stick with `exit` (or `die`), this is also [recommended in the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/#description).

Comment: nice. I didn't get much from docs so posted a question here